# How is the distance between the nodes / length of the link between the nodes defined in a forceSimulation d3?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am looking into this particular example
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Here there is only one usage of value from the dataset, used to define stroke-width. How are some nodes further apart from each other than other nodes?

```
var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
```

The cx,cy, x1,y1,x2,y2 is defined here

```
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
```

what kind of data does d contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulation uses the `nodes` and `links` arrays from the JSON `data`. It fills in the position and speed of the nodes in the **`node`** objects. Each entry of the `nodes` arrays is assigned to a particular node-svg-circle, and it is `d` in all the callbacks.

The length of the links can be specified with the d3.forcelink().links() method (https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_distance). In the example all links have the default preferred distance of `30` units. The other forces determine the actual length of the result link.